# Hardware crc32 instruction for Power7 (ppc64 architecture) CPU with big-endian byte order

Tags: crc

I have seen hardware crc32 instructions for Intel and ARM processors. I am wondering if similar crc32 instruction exist specifically for Power7 processor. I have searched through the Power ISA manual but couldn't find any such crc instruction. Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rcgldr Intel's crc32 and ARM's crc32c instructions both use the same polynomial 0x1EDC6F41. So if we use them to compute crc on the same input buffer, then we would get the same results. I have tried this. I would like to thank you for your input but my question is regarding Power7 crc instruction.

Comment: ARM has crc32 and crc32c. Intel only has crc32c. Both Intel and ARM are bit reflected, crc32:0xedb88320, crc32c: 0x82f63b78. As for power 7 (or 8), I couldn't find a crc32 instruction or a carryless multiply instruction for power isa v2.07.